# Boost Asio - How to know when the handler queue is empty?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am currently posting handlers to my io_service and execute them in a thread pool.

```
io_serv.post( boost::bind(&Class::bar, p1, p2) );
```

My workers run this function:

```
m_mutex.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] Thread Start" << std::endl;
m_mutex.unlock();

size_t tasks = m_serv.run();

m_mutex.lock();
std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] accomplished "
          << tasks << " tasks" << std::endl;
m_mutex.unlock();
```

So far so good but now **I want to trigger an event when the handler queue is empty without killing my active (but waiting) threads.**

Is it possible and how ?

Comment: Are your tasks doing any asynchronous waiting that will cause them to not be handled immediately?  (Similar to `async_receive`?)

Comment: No, they do their job, post new events via signals in the queue. When everything is finished, all threads are just waiting.

Comment: Can you keep a count of handlers posted/executed?  See my answer (to my question) here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166513/boostasio-thread-pools-and-thread-monitoring

Comment: My handlers are posting new events in the queue, it is difficult to keep a count of who did what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time i see using of **asio** as a queue dispatcher. Not bad technique i think.

Well, i suggest you are running **io_service::run** to serve the handlers. As [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload2.html) says, **run** will block until io_service is stopped OR all work has finished. So you can run your "empty queue event" after **io_service::run**:

```
while( !finished ) {
    io_serv.run();
    io_serv.reset();
    io_serv.post( boost::bind(&Class::fill_queue, instance) );
}
```

This in case you have no other asio activity on this io_service and you not using io_service::work.

As mentioned in comments you using **io_service::work** so plan A failed(it will not work since this class prevents exitting on empty queue). Well, you can do `io_serv.post()` after each bunch of `io_serv.post()`-s for thread jobs. The handler can contain waiting with **boost::condition** while other threads finish their work. As you do `post()` for this after actual jobs, i think asio will call it after dispatching all jobs, but its subject for investigation. Anyway that handler can re-`post()` himself to free current thread if condition is not ready yet.

But i think easiest way is to replace **io_service::work** with equialent **while** construct.

Comment: My handlers are posting new events in the queue, so the last empty job is not the last in fact.

Comment: With your solution, at each loop I will be forced to launch new threads, because they would have died after the previous io_serv.run().

Comment: No, you run `io_serv.run()` IN each thread. Use **strand** to prevent simultaneous running of `fill_queue`. You not creating new threads inside `post()` handler, right? Otherwise its not thread pool)