# Event queue using boost::asio and strands: Waiting for new events

Tags: c++, boost, event-handling

So I want to make a synchronous event queue in c++ on a custom thread. As far as I can tell, boost::asio::strand is an excelent candidate for this, with one twist: when asio::run() is called, it only runs while there are events in the strand's queue. The code:

```
this->control_strand_.reset(new boost::asio::strand(control_io_service_));
control_thread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,&control_io_service_));
control_thread_.join();
```

Returns immediately. Now I could go with the answer of [Boost Asio - How to know when the handler queue is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517313/boost-asio-how-to-know-when-the-handler-queue-is-empty), but this has a while-loop-wait in it. I'd rather have it be more event based (aka, wait for a "wrap" call in the while look when the queue is empty). Th only way I can think to do this is completely wrap the strand class, having it trigger a signal whenever "wrap" is called (something like, pseudo code)

```
//some member variables
boost::condition_variable cond_var;
boost::mutex mut;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::strand> control_strand_;
boost::asio::io_service control_io_service_
//while loop,running on event processing thread
void MessageProcessor()
{
  while (true)
  {
    {
      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
      cond_var.wait(lock);
    }
    control_io_service_.run();
  }
}
//post call,from different thread
template <typename Handler>
void wrap(Handler hand)
{
  cond_var.notify_all();
  control_strand_->wrap(hand);
}
```

This will run the queue forever without the while loop (my synchronization is a little off, but thats not an issue atm). Is there a better, more standard, way?

Comment: Why can't you use `io_service` with `io_service::work` object?

Comment: @IgorR. Man, whenever I try to do something in boost i get in the problem that the boost library totally has it done, my googling skills just seems to miss it. This looks like it works. (Just double checking, this would be an "implicit strand" i.e. the queue is emptied in order synchronously?) Put that in an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `io_service` directly, it implements an "implicit strand". To keep it running, just give it `io_service::work` object, like in the `io_service` [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work) (see "Stopping the io_service from running out of work").

Note that `io_service` is intentionally thread-safe, so you can `post()` functors to it from external threads.